# Why won't it let me edit my Developer Story?

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, developer-story

I've been trying to edit existing entries in my Developer Story, but I've come across this weird error. I have a "Feature or Apps" entry, and when I click the edit button, suddenly the "Description" field is empty even though it wasn't before I clicked the edit button. Then I fill it back in, and make a change to the "Technologies" field.

When I click Save, however, it scrolls back to the top of the entry, removes everything I typed in the "Description" field, and resets the changes I made to the "Technologies" field, all without leaving edit mode. What's wrong here? Could someone fix this, or is it a problem with something related to my browser? Also, it doesn't show any error messages.

Comment: there seems a lot wrong in the new profile sites maybe you should post that on the SE site itelf as there is already a huge thread open for it see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372716/347191

Comment: nah, bugs in the developer story, while possibly related to the overall project of making the user profile responsive, isn't related to the activity page being made responsive. It'd warrant it's own post, right here on MSO

Comment: @KevinB Just wondering: what is a "responsive" profile? I didn't read the blog on it, and I may have trouble getting to it. Does "responsive" mean that it updates faster or something?

Comment: Developer Story is a separate feature to user profiles; the current efforts being made on user profiles is to make them mobile responsive (the linked Meta post discusses that). Anyhow, I can confirm this is a bug in Developer Story

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Ostensibly, it means [the site is designed to work well at any browser size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design). In practice, it looks more like they're optimizing the mobile experience at the expense of desktop users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a regression from our [migration to Webpack yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372590/were-migrating-our-javascript). The behavior between Webpack and our previous minifier generated different JS outputs causing some invalid references to functions.

A fix for this has been deployed. You should be able to edit your Dev Stories again